separate frontend and backend from spring boot project
Now I have a spring boot project, I have added the frontend (nextJS) in the root directory
project-root/
|-- frontend/
|--|-- out/
|--|src/
|--|-- main/
|-- pom.xml
when I compile the war file, it will run npm run build inside the frontend folder, and it will output the out folder for static content, then it will move these output file in the src/resource/static folder
then I just need to deploy to war file from target folder into my wildfly service
now my client wants to structure the programme better, they want me to create 2 separate war file, one for frontend and the another one for backend. Can anyone tell me the approach to do this? I have no idea how to perform the result.
I have tried create a directory for frontend and backend, also create a separate pom.xml for these folder
inside the backend just like a regular maven pom.xml configure
inside the frontend it only contains running npm run build
also I have set the application.properties
spring.web.resources.static-locations=file:/frontend/out
to change the location of the static folder path
because when I need to change the frontend code, then I can just rebuild the frontend.war and upload this war into the wildfly service, I don't need to compile the backend.war
project-root/
|-- frontend/
|--|-- pom.xml
|--|-- out/
|-- backend/
|--|-- pom.xml
|--|-- src/
|--|--|-- main/
|-- pom.xml
but I am not sure whether my approach is correct or not, also I need to set up for my nginx
is that for the frontend part:
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/frontend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/;
}

then for the backend part:
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/;
}

